# Python: Conversion of a matrix to ordered form

Tags: python, matrix, classification

I am new to Python. I have a matrix in Python as this:

```
4 4 4 4 1
4 4 4 4 1
1 1 1 1 7
```

I want to convert it to a matrix as this:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7
1   1   0   0   4   0   0   0
2   1   0   0   4   0   0   0
3   4   0   0   0   0   0   1
```

The new matrix has number of columns as the maximum number in the original matrix. The number of rows are the same as number of rows in the actual matrix. The value in new matrix is the count of occurrence of each item.

For ex: 1 appears 4 times in third row of original matrix, so our new matrix has value 4 for [3][1], and so on.

How can I convert this? Thx in advance!

Comment: Is that matrix a file?

Comment: Are the inputs always strictly positive then?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem This matrix is a dynamic matrix in which a column is added on each run. It is the data that I am getting from some server. Each column has the same sum. 
In new matrix, each row has the same sum.

Comment: @Anand: I more asking what the type of the data is: is this some sort of string, or a list of lists?

Comment: @MadPhysicist no. inputs can be 0 too.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem its numpy ndarray.

Comment: If inputs can be 0 as well, then shouldn't the output matrix contain at the beginning an extra column consisting of only 0s?

Comment: @CristiFati yes it would contain in that case. it's made dynamically according to the data

Comment: If it involves _numpy_ you should probably add the tag too (I suppose the task can't be done if I don't have _numpy_ installed).

Comment: @CristiFati I apologise for bad question. Would keep that in mind next time.  It involves numpy.

Comment: @Anand, don't apologize and don't do things next time. Fix it here and now, it's what the edit button is for.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

old_matrix = np.array([[4, 4, 4, 4, 1],
                       [4, 4, 4, 4, 1],
                       [1, 1, 1, 1, 7]])

new_matrix = np.vstack([np.bincount(row, minlength=old_matrix.max() + 1) for row in old_matrix])
```

Comment: Please fix the format of your answer, it is of very low quality

Comment: @triphook It gives error as:: ValueError: object too deep for desired array

Comment: What is the format of your array, exactly?  The above code (I just edited to show how old_matrix is initialized) executes as expected

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
a=[[4,4,4,4,1],[4,4,4,4,1],[1,1,1,1,7]]
m =0
for row in a:
   m = max([max(row),m])
b =[]
for row in a:
   r =[]
   i= 1 #set to zero if 0 is included
   while i<=m:
      c = row.count(i)
      r.append(c) 
      i +=1 
   b.append(r)
print b
```